# Importing XML to MS Access - problems with Chrome authentication

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I posted this question a few days ago on the assumption that this was a VBA issue. Guided by the comments below, I've come to the conclusion that the problem is actually with Chrome not accepting user credentials submitted via URL in our new environment. I've therefore updated the details below to reflect this new train of thought.

For several years I have been successfully pulling XML data into MS Access via VBA. This requires the submission of an URL that follows this format:

```
    https://[UserName]:[Password]@vendorwebsite.com&format=XML
```

This code ran without a problem on our old OS, using Access 2010 on Windows 7. The company is now rolling out a new Windows 10 environment with Office 2016, and our default browser is Chrome 79.

This URL is now failing when submitted via VBA. If I take the same URL and paste it into Chrome directly, the browser strips the credentials from the URL and prompts me to log in manually. Once I've done that, subsequent attempts will return the expected results, but calling the URL from VBA still fails.

If I paste the same URL into my personal computer, it works without the prompt to log in. At home I'm using Chrome 80.

So it appears that what I had misinterpreted as a VBA issue is actually caused by Chrome rejecting user credentials embedded in an URL. I've yet to find an alternative means of expressing the URL to circumvent this, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: To start with, there was no need to change the DOMDocument version, as both exist on both 32 and 64 bit Windows. I don't see anything in your code that should need to change. Have you tried stepping through it with the debugger to see specifically where it stops working? I'm guessing that it's not suceeding with the `xmldoc.selectNodes` call, which would cause the loop to never execute.

Comment: In opposite to`MS XML 3.0`the newer`MS XML 6.0`libary only provides a`DomDocument60`. Check in VBA-Ide -> View -> Object Browser with different versions referenced. So not a bitness issue as Ken noticed. I've done similar on 2007 to 2013 upgrade, without issues by just adapting like you did. As Ken suggested, [Debug](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) your code. For more on debug search for "vba debug."!

Comment: Just recognized "I ... import XML data from an API call". You call a Websites API (e.g Rest) or you call a Windows API. If the latter then that call may go wrong, as Win-API calls may need fixes on bitness change. See [How to convert Windows API declarations in VBA for 64-bit](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?!Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. The more I explore this, the more I'm convinced there's nothing actually wrong with the code. Stepping through the code returns no errors; the script is simply not receiving the expected XML results. I'm beginning to suspect that my firm's proxy settings are blocking the results of the XML call. I'm going to explore this possibility.

Comment: Maybe an`Interner Explorer`security-zones issue, Read [DOM Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms761392(v=vs.85)) till end. To debug, you should add a watch on`xmldoc`and check the received values with a breakpoint right after`xmldoc.Load strUrl`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, all. Based on your input, I've come to the conclusion that the VBA code is fine, and it's actually my browser that is causing the problem. I've updated the question to reflect this.